# Changing from using Model to ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an index page that lists all users. This has the following in the Users controller -

```
 public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(userRepository.AllIncluding(user => user.Roles));
        }
```

and then the view starts with

```
@model IEnumerable<TRS.Models.User>
```

and then uses

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
```

to loop through all users in my model.

I now need to change my model to a ViewModel that contains both the User model and an extended UserDetails model.

I have changed my Index view to use the view model -

```
@model IEnumerable<TRS.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel>
```

But I don't know how I should be going about filling the ViewModel in my controller -

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {

            var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
            {
                UserName = "???"
                FirstName = "???"
                LastName = "???"
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I assume I need to create an instance of the view model and then pass it to the view. But I don't understand how I can get data against each individual item. I'll obviously need to get all data for all users here and then loop through them in my view. Any ideas what I should be going in the controller above? What should replace the "???" with that will fill the viewModel with all the data? Or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks

Edit - Models added -

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
}


 public class UserDetails
    {

        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Edit - From View -

```
<td>
                @foreach (Role role in item.Roles){
                @role.RoleName <br />
    }</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var usersVm = userRepository
        .AllIncluding(user => user.Roles)
        .Select(user => new RegisterViewModel
        {
            UserName = user.UserName
            FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName
            LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName
        });
    return View(usersVm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to be partially working now in that my view displays the username (but no other data) the other data comes from the UserDetails model. Should this data also be available now?

Comment: What other data are you talking about? What's UserDetails? Please show your models.

Comment: I have edited above to include my User and UserDetails model. thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to illustrate how to retrieve the FirstName and LastName properties from the UserDetails.

Comment: Thank you Darin. The related data is now showing. However I get an error for my role (I've added the part of my view that displays the role above). For the line @foreach (Role role in item.Roles){   I get an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', but when I remove the role column the related data shows. It seems from your code in the controller the Roles data was still being included so nor sure why the error is occuring. Any idea? Sorry, I had just forgot to include - Roles = user.Roles. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Automapper](http://automapper.org/) was created for this very thing.  I'd highly recommend it.

Take a read of [getting started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) section of wiki.

Once you have it configured your controller code would look something like this:

```
List<RegisterViewModel> registrants = 
                  Mapper.Map<List<User>, List<RegisterViewModel>>(users);
```

Though you might want to consider a viewmodel that has a list of registrants on them but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear from your question what UserDetails look like.

You should not use IEnumerable<RegisterViewModel> in your view. The RegisterViewModel should be the container of everything you will need in the view:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var usersDetails = GetUserDetails(userRepository.AllIncluding(user => user.Roles));

        var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            UserDetails = usersDetails.ToList(),
            SomeMoreDataRequiredByTheView= "1"
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

   //you can use automapper to do this dirty job.
   private IEnumerable<UserDetails> GetUserDetails(IEnumerable<User> users)
   {
       foreach(var user in users)
       {
           yield return new UserDetails()
           {
               FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
               // Other stuff you want

           };
       }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, in my example UserName comes from the User Model and both FirstName and LastName come from the UserDetails model (which just holds extended info about the user)

Answer (score 0):

Your viewModel

```
    Public Class RegisterViewModel
   {
      Public IEnumerable<TRS.Models.User> AllUsers {get;set;}
      Public IEnumerable<TRS.Models.UserDetails> UserDetails {get;set;}
   }
```

Then in your controller

```
public ViewResult Index()
{

    var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
    {
        AllUsers = userRepository.AllIncluding(user => user.Roles).ToList()
    };

    var DetailList = new list<TRS.Models.UserDetails>();
    foreach(var user in viewModel.AllUsers)
    {
        DetailList.add(new userDetails
       {
          name = user.Name,
          age = user.age, 
          ....
       }
    }

    viewModel.UserDetails = DetailList;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```